# How to remove space in jQuery using Select2 plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

in database the value is saved as `Jack, Mike` which have space between `,` and `M`. But when I want to display at the frontend in edit form using dropdown `select2` plugin, an error appear at console. It seems like I need to remove the space in between `, M` then it will appear in the dropdown `select2`. the question how to remove the space during to display at the dropdown edit form?

Currently it just display the first name only which is `Jack`.

DB: `Jack, Mike`

JS

```
$("#editLayer2TaskOwner").val(response.data[0]["task_owner"]);

// To allow Select2 to choose selected as stored from DB
$(response.data).each(function(key,value){
    var owners = value.task_owner.split(',');
    $(owners).each(function(k,v){
        $("#editLayer2TaskOwner").append($("<option selected>", {
            response: v,
            text: v
        }));
    });
    $("#editLayer2TaskOwner").val(owners).trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a reproducible example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very easy just `split` with ***,*** and ***space***. It will work. change your code like below.

```
$("#editLayer2TaskOwner").val(response.data[0]["task_owner"]);
// To allow Select2 to choose selected as stored from DB
$(response.data).each(function(key,value){
    var owners = value.task_owner.split(', ');
    $(owners).each(function(k,v){
        $("#editLayer2TaskOwner").append($("<option selected>", {
            response: v,
            text: v
        }));
    });
    $("#editLayer2TaskOwner").val(owners).trigger("change");
});
```